# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 PAGINADOR AJAX

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un paginador AJAX que me consulte y me devuelva un JSON. Tengo el siguiente Javascrypt llamado "buscar.js". También tengo un archivo llamado "ajax-buscar.php"

```
var nombre = "null";

const botones = document.querySelectorAll('#paginador a');
for(let i=0; i< botones.length; i++){
    botones[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        const num = e.target.dataset.pagina;
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('nombre',nombre);
        fd.append('numero',num);
    
        fetch('http://localhost/buscador/ajax-buscar.php', 

             { method: 'POST',
             body: fd
            })
            .then(function(j){
                return j.json();
            })
            .then(function(d){
                console.log(d);
            });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Este es el
ajax-buscar.php

```
<?php
include('funciones.php' );
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$respuesta = buscar( $nombre, $numero );
echo json_encode( $respuesta );
```

Cuando doy clic en los botones y me fijo en la consola me sale la frase "Unexpected token"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando busco en el network encuentro este error que al parecer viene de una funcion archivo llamado funcion.php que me hace 2 consultas; 1 para que me busque lo que pongo en el buscador del AJAX que estoy creando y la 2 para hacer la consulta de la botonera del AJAX el network me muestra lo siguiente

[image: Network]

Alguna idea de porque se me origina ese error de Unexpected token < ¿?

Comment: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" es un error genérico y común en JS cuando se hacen llamadas asíncronas si se produce algún error de tipo 500 en el servidor, tienes que encontrar y resolver el error en tu backend.

Answer (score 0):

Debes fijarte en qué está haciendo el archivo `funciones.php` en la línea 26. A ciegas me parece que en esa línea el archivo funciones.php debe esperar un set de resultados de una consulta de base de datos y por algún motivo esa consulta está devolviendo `NULL`, `EMPTY` o algo similar y por eso se desata el error.

Answer (score 0):

En efecto como dijo el compañero el problema estaba en el backend (Que dolor de cabeza ) después de revisarlo mucho casi con "LUPA" me percate que en lugar de tener una llamada al CAMPO del registro lo que estaba haciendo era invocar al nombre de la TABLA es decir el error estaba en la consulta "SQL query" un error de sintaxis...

Eh corregido el nombre por un "ID" (Como muestro en la imagen) y un JSON encode que puse para ver si recibía datos y el bucle while entonces funciono. Me imagino que hay gente experta en esto para los que no aquí una pista y puedan continuar si se atoren.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]